# Need to calculate % Share in one of my query

Tags: sql

Can anyone help me to calculate % share for one of my query. Any help is appreciated.

% SHARE CALCULATION: This is how  we need to calculate % share.
Total borrowers having balance > 500000, sum of balances for all those borrowers divide by all borrowers sum.

```
(
(
SELECT SUM(OUTSTANDING_BAL)
FROM MyView
GROUP BY BORROWER_NAME
HAVING SUM(OUTSTANDING_BAL) > 500000 -- SUM OF BORROWER HAVING BALANCE > 500000
)
/ -- DIVIDE BY
(SELECT SUM(OUTSTANDING_BAL) FROM MyView) -- TOTAL SUM 
)*100
```

Please help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Get rid of the `GROUP BY` in your first `SELECT` statement and change `HAVING` to `WHERE`.
Also try `CAST [select statement] AS FLOAT`.  Dividing in SQL doesn't work well unless you use FLOATS.

Other than that, please specify the exact issue you are running into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want one query with this information, use conditional aggregation:

```
select (sum(case when outstanding_bal > 500000 then outstanding_bal else 0 end) /
        sum(outstanding_bal)
       ) as ratio
from (select borrower_name, sum(outstanding_bal) as outstanding_bal
      from MyView
      group by borrower_name
     ) b;
```

This assumes that borrows could have multiple records that you want to add up.  If you just want to consider individual rows with regards to the threshhold, then the query is simpler:

```
select (sum(case when outstanding_bal > 500000 then outstanding_bal else 0 end) /
        sum(outstanding_bal)
       ) as ratio
from MyView;
```